# Is this the correct way to find the intrinsic equation of a parabola?

Tags: differential-geometry

$$\begin{align}
\\y=x^2,y’=2x=\tan\psi
\\s=\int_0^x\sqrt{2t+1}\,dt
\\s=\frac{(2x+1)^{(3/2)}-1}{3}
\\s=\frac{(\tan\psi+1)^{(3/2)}-1}{3}
\end{align}$$

Is this correct?

And the curvature would be:

$$
\\\frac{d\psi}{ds}=\frac{1}{\frac{ds}{d\psi}}=
\\\frac{2}{\sec^2\psi(\tan\psi+1)^{(1/2)}}=
\\\frac{2}{(2x+1)(2x+1)^{(1/2)}}=
\\\frac{2}{(2x+1)^{(3/2)}}
$$

... right?

Comment: Naive question.  What is intrinsic?

Comment: @herbsteinberg the intrinsic equation describes a curve by the relation between its arc length and its angle of inclination (both w.r.t. any arbitrary fixed point/axis)

Comment: @herbsteinberg $s=f(\psi)$ as opposed to the usual $r=f(t)$

Comment: Go back to square one. Look at your arclength integral.

Comment: @TedShifrin ah - it should be $4t^2$?

Comment: Yup. A famous integral results …

Comment: Yes, but better to use trigonometric substitution. Pay attention.